# Does there exist a function $f : X \to Y$ such that $f \in Y$?

Tags: set-theory

> Does there exist a function $f : X \to Y$ such that $f \in Y$?

I think this is related to Russell's paradox, but I'm not exactly sure how.

---

**Added Later:** As Brian points out, given any function $f : X \to Y_0$, we can just add $f$ to the codomain, that is $f : X \to Y_0\cup\{f\}$ is a function which satisfies my initial request.

However, what if we try to find a *surjective* function $f : X \to Y$ such that $f \in Y$?

Comment: +1 wrestling with definitions often produces understanding

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $V_\omega$ be the set of hereditarily finite sets (i.e. sets which are finite, and all their elements are finite, and so on). It is immediate from this definition that if $x\in V_\omega$ and $y\in x$ then $y\in V_\omega$, and if $x\subseteq V_\omega$ is finite, then $x\in V_\omega$.

It's not hard to show that if $X\in V_\omega$ then $\mathcal P(X)\in V_\omega$, and if $X,Y\in V_\omega$ then $X\times Y\in V_\omega$.

Take any set $X\in V_\omega$, then any function $f$ from $X$ into $V_\omega$ is actually a function into a finite subset of $V_\omega$, therefore there exists a finite $Y\in V_\omega$, such that $f\subseteq X\times Y$. Therefore $f\in V_\omega$.

---

For the addition, suppose that $f\colon X\to Y$ and $f\in Y$. If there exists some $x\in X$ such that $\langle x,f\rangle\in f$, then this a contradiction to the axiom of regularity because $\langle x,f\rangle =\{\{x\},\{x,f\}\}$ by the Kuratowski definition of an ordered pair, because this  means that $$f\in\{x,f\}\in\langle x,f\rangle\in f.$$
In particular $f$ cannot be surjective.

Note that regularity is necessary for this proof, otherwise we can have a set $X=\{X\}$. Note that in this case: $$\langle X,X\rangle=\{\{X\},\{X,X\}\}=\{\{X\}\}=\{X\}=X.$$

Therefore $X\times X=X$ which is the identity function from $X$ onto itself.

Comment: I'm watching for the proof that regularity is necessary to prove that no such surjection exists.

Comment: @dfeuer: There you go.

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists) the implication of the axiom of regularity which is being contradicted? Is there an easier way to see how $f \in \{x, f\} \in \langle x, f\rangle \in f$ contradicts the axiom?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, that's the issue here. One can also directly see that $F=\{f,\{x,f\},\langle x,f\rangle\}$ does not have an $\in$-minimal element. That is, for every $z\in F$ we have $z\cap F\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: My aborted question was whether it is necessary specifically to assume the existence of a Quine atom, or whether the negation of regularity is enough.

Comment: @dfeuer: I think that the answer is somewhere in the middle, but I don't know.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It seems likely that it is necessary at least to assume a membership loop (rather than, e.g., an infinite descending chain of distinct sets), but I don't know if even that is sufficient. Your example made use of some very special properties of Quine atoms, and it's not clear whether there are any other examples. Thankfully, this does not seem to be a very important question.

Answer (score 12):

Let $X=\varnothing$, $Y=\{\varnothing\}$; the unique function $f:X\to Y$ is $\varnothing$, which is an element of $Y$.

**Added:** For a slightly less trivial example, let $X=\{0\}$ and $Y=\big\{1,\{\langle 0,1\rangle\}\big\}$; then $\{\langle 0,1\rangle\}$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ that is an element of $Y$. In general start with any function $f$ from $X$ to some set $Y_0$, and let $Y=Y_0\cup\{f\}$; then $f$, regarded now as a subset of $X\times Y$, is a function from $X$ to $Y$ that is an element of $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

This **definition of function** is from general topology by Engelking:

> Any subset of the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ is a relation. The relation $f\subset X\times Y$ is called a function from $X$ to $Y$, or a mapping of $X$ to $Y$, if for every $x\in X$ there exists a $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$ and **$y$ is uniquely determined by $x$, i.e., $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,y') \in f$ imply $y=y'$.**

If $f \in Y$, then there exists subset of $X\times Y$ such that it is the element of $Y$.

**For example, if $Y$ has $\emptyset$, then the answer to the question is always true.**

Comment: I don't see why the answer is "no" according to your definition.  Could you explain?

Comment: Brian has provided two sound examples.

Comment: I don't understand the last two sentences you added.  Could you explain what you mean by "it is the element of $Y$" and "if $Y$ has $\emptyset$"?

Comment: @Trevor, I suppose that vacuously (if $X$ is non-empty). It does miss the point of the question, though.

Comment: @TrevorWilson: You should put attention into the definition of function which is given above.

Comment: It is the usual definition of a function.  I am familiar with it.  On a second reading, I can guess that you mean "it is an element of $Y$" and "if $\emptyset \in Y$" respectively.

Comment: @TrevorWilson: $f$ is a subset of $X\times Y$, and $f$ is in $Y$, so we conclude that if $Y$ has an element which is a subset of $X\times Y$, then it can be in $Y$.

Comment: Now it seems like you are assuming $f \in Y$ in order to prove $f \in Y$.  Probably you understand, but your writing is not very clear.